# Actionbar scherlock is not refreshed when the orientation is changed

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I use Sherlock action bar in my application. I used "ifRoom|withText" feature  in my menu. If I test my code in portrait mode, I can see only icon and if I  rotate orientation to landscape, still I see only icon. On the other hand, if I run with landscape, I can see text and icon on portrait and landscape. This means that When the screen is rotated, action bar is not refreshed. How can I fix?

In menu, I have

```
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
```

Also I used this line in my manifest file to fixed

```
    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```

but it didn't work. And I run my code android 2.3

Also I used fragment in my activity,

```
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    ft = fm.beginTransaction();

    mFragment1 = fm.findFragmentByTag("f1");

    if (mFragment1 == null) {

        mFragment1 = new MenuFragment();
        ft.add(mFragment1, "f1");

    }

    ft.commit();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Handling configuration changes is not supported with ActionBarSherlock.

On pre-ICS, ActionBarSherlock is NOT part of the decor view like the native action bar and is therefore subject to the same restrictions as your content view. By handling configuration changes you are not allowing the library to adapt to the change and therefore will see incorrect display or certain parts.

The Android documentation discourages handling config changes as well. Avoid them at all costs, especially when using ActionBarSherlock.

On a related note, I'm still trying to work around this for future versions of the library but for now avoiding is recommended.

Comment: I have some code that's been sitting in my onDestroy method, but I have just added ABS, which now calls onDestroy when you rotate.  Do you think my best bet is to move that code into the handler for the back button?  Thanks

Comment: You're welcome to override `onDestroy` so long as you remember to call the superclass method.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I was not previously destroying activities on rotate.  So I moved the code to the onBackPressed method instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to re-create the ActionBar menu on config change

```
invalidateOptionsMenu();
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, I tried your function in config change but it didn't work. Do you have any other idea?

Comment: My only other suggestion would be to try supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();

Comment: Thank you tony, but still it didnt any effect. I dont know, where is the problem