# Application label font not preserved on orientation change

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I am not able to preserve the font for my application label on screen orientation change. Currently I am setting the font using the below code in the onCreate method of SherlockFragmentActivity.

```
titleId = Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("action_bar_title", "id", "android");
if(titleId == 0)
    titleId = com.actionbarsherlock.R.id.abs__action_bar_title; 
mAppName = (TextView) findViewById(titleId);
Typeface face = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/handsean.ttf");
mAppName.setTypeface(face);
```

On Orientation change the font reverts back to the default. I tried preserving state using manifest.xml but it didnot help. it preserves everything except the label font. Can someone suggest how this can be done ?

Thanks for stopping by and reading this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you tried setting `android:configChanges="orientation"` and handling the orientation change with `onConfigurationChanged()`?

edit: also explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10589676/actionbar-scherlock-is-not-refreshed-when-the-orientation-is-changed?rq=1) why it's not functioning.

Comment: I believe Jake's comment in that post sums it all up. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

```
**Yes we can do this.

Override onConfigurationChanged
set the action bar title inside a handler with a delay of 200.**

@Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                //your code to set the action bar title
                setActionBarTitle(title);
            }
        }, 200);
    }
```