# Fully retain WebView in fragment after rotation

Tags: android, webview

I'm currently having a WebView placed in a fragment like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setRetainInstance(true);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
        mContext = container.getContext();
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        LinearLayout view = (LinearLayout) mInflater.inflate(R.layout.post_view_layout, container,false);           
        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        _viewCache = view;
        _post_WebView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.post_webview);
        setupWebView(_post_WebView); //This method sets up the webview (javascript mode etc.) and set the url to load
        return view;
}
```

Now whenever I rotate, the activity that contains this fragment gets recreated (I can't use the `configChanges="orientation"` attribute for the manifest because I'm using ABS)
Because of `setRetainInstance(true)` the fragment, it's layout and all variables get retained fine and all, but whenever I try to scroll or click in the retained WebView I get a `BadTokenException` (probably because the original activity used for it's context is destroyed during rotation).

I could solve this by just recreating the WebView with the new activity context after rotation, but since the webview shows a input form, recreating it after rotation might prove tedious to users. (I already tried saving the state using the `saveState` and `restoreState` methods of the WebView, but to no avail)

Is there any way to restore or retain the WebView in it's complete pre-rotation state without generating a `BadTokenException`, just like it would when the `configChanges="orientation"` attribute has been added?

Comment: Why can't you use configChanges="orientation" when using ABS? I'm using ABS and configChanges="orientation" at the same time WITH a webview. What version of Android are you testing on?

Comment: When using configChanges="orientation" combined with ABS on pre-Honeycomb some features like icons or tabs might get unresponsive (which happened in my application).
See this question answered by the creator of ABS: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10589676/actionbar-scherlock-is-not-refreshed-when-the-orientation-is-changed

Comment: `setRetainInstance` retains the fragment, but not the view inside the fragment.